# What is better way instead of use GOTO in Laravel

Tags: laravel, eloquent, goto

Now I have to use GOTO for some logic in Laravel 5.6v.

How can I make code that works the same as GOTO and more beautiful code? :)

```
public function job_finished_search(Request $request)
{
    $rFrom = $request->input('datepicker_from');
    $rTo = $request->input('datepicker_to');
    $rName =$request->customer_name;

    if($rFrom == null){
        if($rTo == null){
            if($rName == null){
            Flash::error('Search result not found');
            return redirect(route('pdf.index'));
            }
            $query = Job::onlyTrashed()
                        ->where('is_trash', 0)
                        ->where('customer_name', $rName)
                        ->orderBy('created_at', 'desc');
                        goto A;
        }

        elseif($rTo != null){
            if($rName == null){
                $query = Job::onlyTrashed()
                ->where('is_trash', 0)
                ->where('created_at', '<=', Carbon::parse($rTo)->endOfDay())
                ->orderBy('created_at', 'desc');
                goto A;
            }
        ...
        ...
}

A: $job_ids = $query->pluck('id')->all();
```

Comment: is goto working outside of function?

Comment: @arun, this function is just working as query for View page.

Answer (score 1):

A Lot more cleaner way,

```
$buildquery=Job::onlyTrashed()->where('is_trash', 0);

if($request->filled('customer_name')){
    $buildquery->where('customer_name', $request->customer_name);
}

if($request->filled('datepicker_to')){
    $buildquery->where('created_at', '<=', Carbon::parse($request->datepicker_to)->endOfDay());
}

$result = $buildquery->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->get();

$job_ids = $result->pluck('id');
```

you are not using `$rFrom`, anywhere so i omitted it.

Comment: $rFrom included into " . . . " because question was exceed to limit. thank you to give your time :)